# How to assign new keys to a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP that creates an array of jobs as $jobs. However I'd like the keys to be [ref] rather than 0, 1, 2 etc

```
$xml_feed = new DOMDocument();
$xml_feed->load('http://jobs.recruitsosimple.com/job/762/xml');
$jobs = array();
foreach ($xml_feed->getElementsByTagName('job') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'ref' => $node->getElementsByTagName('referencenumber')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($jobs, $item);
}
```

The array created is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Theatre Nurse
            [ref] => MT29
            [link] => http://jobs.com/job/1192/29
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ward Nurse
            [ref] => MT39
            [link] => http://jobs.com/1192/762/39
        )

)
```

But I would like the keys to be

```
Array
(
    [MT29] => Array
        (
            [title] => Theatre Nurse
            [ref] => MT29
            [link] => http://jobs.com/job/1192/29
        )

    [MT39] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ward Nurse
            [ref] => MT39
            [link] => http://jobs.com/1192/762/39
        )

)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: just create your enties like that: `$jobs[$ref] = $item;` instead of the arraypush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
array_push($jobs, $item);
```

to this:

```
$jobs[$item['ref']] = $item;
```

Comment: @Jeff OK, thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I haven't really used StackOverflow so it's good to know. I just noticed that you also answered the question but you put it as a comment rather than an answer. Why?

Comment: because I didn't have the time for a real (good) answer. Writing it as a comment was easier & quicker.

Comment: Thanks so much. That also helped me to learn that 
`array_push($jobs, $item);`
does the same as `$jobs[] = $item;`